# Difference between winch pulling vs lifting capacity - how to calculate?

Tags: torque

Trying to figure out if a 4x4 winch that is rated to pull 3000lb (1360kg) could be used to hoist the 500kg keel on my trailer boat.  Hoping someone can walk me through the math.

My understanding is that to dead lift 500kg 1m I would need to exert 4900 Nm of force (since W=mgd; 500kg x 9.8 x 1m).  I have set up a 6:1 pulley system so in theory that means I only need 4900/6 = 816.66 Nm?

How can I calculate how much force in Nm a winch rated to pull 1360kg is capable of exerting?  Manufacturer's specifications don't list torque but do list drum diameter (30mm) and gear ratio (153:1).  Can't seem to find a formula for how winch pull rating is calculated but assume it needs to incorporate friction and allow for the fact that the winch is not supporting the full weight of the object being pulled?  Or am I over-complicating this?  All help much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

This should be a long comment to help you edit your question.

---

I think you may be confusing Torque with Energy, because dimensionally are the same -- although their units are different i.e. Nm and Joule respectively.

---

When you lift a weight by 1 m the potential energy difference (or the work of the gravitiational force) is indeed

$$W = m\cdot g\cdot h = F_w \cdot h$$

where:

- W is the work of gravitational force in Joule (or $kg\cdot \frac{m}{s^2}$)
- m is the mass (500 kg)
- g is the acceleration of gravity (m/s^2)
- $F_w$ is the weight force and its equal to $mg$
- h is the height difference [m]

In this case the Weight (Force) and the displacement are parallel.

---

In the case of Torque, the force and the displacement are perpendicular (see images below).

[image]

**Figure: source:**

[image]
**Figure: source:**

You may notice that although the equation is still Force times distance ($T= F\cdot d$), the Force and distance are perpendicular.

### Bottom line

if your winch is rated for 1360 kg, then it should be able to generate a force able to dead lift a weight of 500 kg (baring frictional losses).

if you use your pulley with 6:1 advantage you ought to be able to dead lift a lot more.

Comment: About 3 times as much. Typical efficiency of a 6:1 fall is about 50%. Then there's the force needed to destroy the oyster shell that got wedged in the slot. Those things are a lot tougher than you would think ;)